# opencpu does not show installed packages

Tags: r, docker, package, opencpu

Let me confess first I am new to Docker / opencpu world. here is the issue.

1. I installed Docker from opencpu site on my windows 10 box.
2. I was able to successfully run the docker by "docker run --name myDocker  -t -p 80:80 -p 8004:8004 opencpu/rstudio".
3. I successfully installed my R package by "R CMD INSTALL /tmp/AnotherPackage_0.1.0.tar.gz".
4. Only issue now is I cant see my Package in http://localhost/ocpu/test/. so in below figure I cant see my package in right box (which shows all the other packages).
   [image]

If I do /library/AnotherPackage in Endpoint text box I can see my package's description etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably installed the package in another library. Can you show us the output of your `R CMD INSTALL` line? In particular the final line that starts with *installing to...*.

To install into the global library, either install as user `opencpu`:

```
sudo su opencpu
R CMD INSTALL /tmp/AnotherPackage_0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Or install as root:

```
sudo -i
R CMD INSTALL /tmp/AnotherPackage_0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, normal R CMD INSTALL command was installing it under '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
However, with sudo su opencpu it was installed under '/usr/local/lib/opencpu/site-library'. which is perfect as I can see my package in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running it as opencpu user, which means user installed packages are in `/ocpu/user/{username}/library/{pkgname}/`. See [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/rstudio/) how to get a root shell so that your package is in `/ocpu/library/{pkgname}/` as you expected.